# Can you identify this Sachs hub?

Tags: hub, freewheel, identify-this-bike

I recently picked this up along with a couple of old wheels.

I don't know it's age or history. I've only got as far as identifying it as a Sachs.

There are no other markings apart from the logo shown in the photo.

[image]

Comment: I'd say it's a hub.  Freewheel, looks like 32 spoke from here.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Yes it's clearly a hub. The question is what model?

Comment: The spacers on the axle are a bit odd-looking.  That may give you a clue, or it may be that they're after-market.

Comment: What are you looking to know specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hub is a SACHS Maillard 'New Success'. Don't pin me down on the date, but it's got to be from the late 80s - a couple of years before the branch was acquired by SRAM.